# Programmatically add a UILabel above my WKWebView in iOS 10 + Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, webkit, programmatically-created

To my understanding, a `WKWebView` cannot be created in a Storyboard. I had to create it programmatically in one of my instances of ViewController with the following code:

```
 override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
 }
```

The problem I'm facing is I'd like to have a UILabel placed above `webView`, that spans the width of the device. Right below it, without any visible space, I'd want the `webView` placed. So, if my label is say, 20 pixels in height, the webView would technically be placed 21 pixels lower than where it is now.

In a Storyboard this is obviously a trivial task; how is it done programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

[André Slotta's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41913713/5327882) should work using [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html). I want to show another solution using [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutanchor) (Hints are in the code comments). The third alternative would be [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint). For more informations you get [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) an overview of all three options

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

  var webView: WKWebView!
  var label: UILabel!

  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    setupLabel()

    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!)
    webView.load(request)

    view.addSubview(webView)

    // x, y, width and height of the web view
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    // put the top anchor just below the bottom anchor of the label
    // with this the web view is directly below your label
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true  
  }

  func setupLabel() {
    label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "label"
    label.backgroundColor = .gray
    label.textColor = .red
    view.addSubview(label)

    // x, y, width and height of the label
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    // the height of your label (In your case 20 pixels)
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This worked without error for WKWebView on Xcode 13.3 and Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

if you need a solution using constraints do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var label: UILabel!
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label.text = "some text"

        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.google.de")!)
        webView.load(request)

        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(webView)

        // horizontal constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[label]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["label": label]))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["webView": webView]))

        // vertical constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[label][webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["label": label, "webView": webView]))
    }
}
```

here is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tested this? the webView displays/renders fine, but the label is no where to be seen.

Comment: I have and I can see it :) did you remove your `loadView()` code?

Comment: I did. Looking into where the problem might be now.

Comment: `'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
|[label]| `

Comment: did you create the label and add it as a subview? `view.addSubview(label)`

Comment: ah I broke the order of execution; need to figure out why the label isn't displaying now.

Comment: the 20px requirement is not in the rules in the code?

Comment: I do not think there was a pixel requirement. He just wanted to explain where he expects the label to be...

Answer (score 0):

You could add the UILabel and WKWebView into a UIScrollView. Just disable the scrolling and bouncing on the webview and it should automatically adjust to the height of the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the `WKWebView` the view of the view controller, make the `WKWebView` a subview of the viewController's view. You can do this in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.

```
var webView: WKWebView!
let label = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)

    ... // Other customization here
    view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Then in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you can position the views manually

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    webView.frame = ...
    label.frame = ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code could be done in most of the ViewController's lifecycle, preferably when the view isn't rendered yet ( so either init, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear ).

Place the UI label with height 20px and width to be screen width :

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.width, height: 20))
view.addSubview(label)
```

Place the WKWebView underneath, so the WKWebView origin's would be (0, 20), and the height would be ( screen height - 20 )

```
let wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:20, width: view.frame.width, height : view.frame.height - 20))
view.addSubview(wkWebView)
```

The `view` here is the view of the ViewController itself.

That's pretty much it ! You can layout view just by changing frame of the view itself and then add it as the subview of the main view. If you want flexible views, then you would had to implement some LayoutConstraint code by hand, which is much more complex than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit), you could accomplish this as follows:

```
<LMColumnView spacing="0">
    <UILabel text="This is the label" textAlignment="center" backgroundColor="#eeeeee"/>
    <WKWebView id="webView" weight="1"/>
</LMColumnView>
```

[image]